# Can't locate XML/DOM.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::DOM module)

Tags: xml, perl, cpan, rouge

I am new user for the Perl language where executing a Perl script comparison based on ROUGE tool.

I didn't get my result on a specific dataset. Please suggest what to do to avoid such type of error.

I am getting this error when I execute `runROUGE-test.pl` from the terminal.

It always shows the same error i.e `Can't locate XML/DOM.pm in @INC`

```
tushar@ubuntu:~/Desktop/RELEASE-1.5.5$ ./runROUGE-test.pl

./ROUGE-1.5.5.pl -e ../data -c 95 -2 -1 -U -r 1000 -n 4 -w 1.2 -a ROUGE-test.XML > ../sample-output/ROUGE-test-c95-2-1-U-r1000-n4-w1.2-a.out
**Can't locate XML/DOM.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2** /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ../ROUGE-1.5.5.pl line 173.
```

Comment: `cpan install XML::DOM`

Comment: I needed to run the install command as sudo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the full text of your error message is this

> ```
> Can't locate XML/DOM.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::DOM module) (@INC contains: ...
> ```

There's a very good clue there that you may need to install the module, which you can do using `cpanm XML::DOM` or `cpan XML::DOM`. If neither of those options work for you then you should ask another question

Comment: perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::DOM'

Answer (score 1):

I encountered an issue where the script ROUGE-1.5.5.pl mentioned this version of perl: #!/usr/bion/perl which happened to be an old one 5.18.2

So `cpan install XML::DOM` was installing the module for the version 5.28.1 and therefore I was still getting the same error with the module installed.

Solution: Add this to the script: `$ nano ROUGE-1.5.5.pl`

Add the current version of perl that has the module (in my case was `#!/Applications/anaconda3/bin/perl`)

To find out which version of perl you are using and you updated with `XML::DOM`, run:
`$ which perl`

Answer (score 0):

For those who are not working on PERL but stumble across this issue, this worked for me

`sudo apt-get install libxml-parser-perl`

My exact issue - Running the evaluation script for https://github.com/allenai/scitldr.